# Tag synonym proposal: [буква] --> [буквы]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, retag-request

There are 2 questions tagged with [буква](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0) (singular), whereas there are 33 questions tagged with [буквы](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%8b) (plural).

Either the 2 should simply be retagged with an edit, or perhaps the former tag should be made a synonym of the latter:

[буква](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0) --> [буквы](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%8b)

---

Both of these 2 questions also have the tag [звук](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba) (which has a total of 3 questions). This tag could probably be merged [фонетика](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) or [фонология](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%8f).

---

I don't yet have the required stats to propose synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually inclined to merge both these tags with `алфавит`.

That's what I'll do in two days unless I hear otherwise.

Comment: The questions on [буквы] are usually about individual letters though, where as at least some of the [алфавит] questions are about the whole set; it *might* be useful to keep the [алфавит] tag.

Comment: For example, I'd argue that this question:  [When to use ∂ and when to use the g-type for little д?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2919/when-to-use-∂-and-when-to-use-the-g-type-for-little-д)  
is mis-tagged, as it's not at all about the alphabet, but it is about letters.